# How can I compare data from an Excel file with an Access 2003 database?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, contacts, microsoft-access-2007

I'm wondering if there is a way compare data from an Excel file with an Access 2003 database?

I have a list of contacts in an Excel File and also within Access 2003. I would like to know if any of the contacts are duplicated in my list of contacts in Access 2003 or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do the comparison would be to import the Excel data into a new table in your Access database file.  Then you could run queries in Access comparing the records in the two tables.  Once you are finished with the new table, with the imported Excel data, the table can be deleted.

If the sheet in the Excel file doesn't have column headings in the first row then copy the data onto a new sheet and insert column headings into the first row.  This might be easier than assigning column headings one field at a time during the import process.  I usually avoid spaces in the column headings that will be used for field names.  Access will offer to add a key field and I usually let it...shouldn't matter either way.  When you do the import make sure to select the correct sheet in Excel.

Importing data from Excel into Access is easy and it should only take a few minutes.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Should it be the same heading names from the Access 2003?

Comment: The column names don't need to be same...just something that will make sense.  You can always quickly change the field names in Access after you do the import.

Comment: How do I run the queries. When you say run queries, do I run it with the new table? or the existing table ?

Comment: I already imported the Excel file into Access now I have 2 tables in the access 2007. I also created a query for both. Now how can I compare the 2 tables?